# Flow: is not a polymorphic type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static-analysis, flowtype

i just integrated [flow](https://flow.org/) for the first time to check my javascript sources statically.

I am struggling with a error flow finds and i am not able to solve it on my own. Its about using es6 classes and inheritance. More specific i created some react Components and they should inherit some methods.

I have a Callout Component, that represents a callout message of unspecified severity. To make things a little more simple i thought about providing a ErrorMessage Component, that inherits the Callout Component. My classes Structure looks like:

```
React.Component
    > AbstractComponent (here i add some project-wide helpers for i18n and so on
        > Callout (this represents a pretty message on the screen)
            > ErrorMessage (this represents an error)
```

Flow tells me:

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/js/Components/Generic/ErrorMessage.js:14:43

statics of Callout [1] is not a polymorphic type.

     11│     icon: string
     12│ };
     13│
 [1] 14│ export default class ErrorMessage extends Callout<Props> {
     15│
     16│     static get defaultProps(): Props {
     17│         return {
```

The part `Callout<Props>` gets highlighted

I already define the Props Type for the Callout class, so this might be the problem but i cant solve it on my own.

A similar error is thrown a few lines below, where i try to access a parent method by addressing super.content (content is a get-method of Callout).

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE: Why do i want to use class inheritance?**

The inheritance Callout > ErrorMessage just exists to reduce redundant code, but its not necessary, so lets ignore this and talk about a more common case:

I want to have a class `AbstractComponent` to make common things in my project easier.

**Some examples:**

Printing of translation strings: In order to make the component multilingual, i created a utility class to generate translation strings, inside a component it works like

```
function render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {new Translation(
                'namespace',
                'key',
                [some, args],
                `${some} fallback message with optional ${args}`
            ).toString()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

In order to use this, every component in my stack ends up with the import statement on top

```
import Translation from "../Core/Translation"
```

or in the best case

```
import t from "../Core/Translation"
```

I use webpack to build a bundle and webpack seems to blow up the compiled javascript with every import statement you use. So i figured - to reduce coding effort and bundle size - i provide a intermediate component class, that adds some utility methods like:

```
class AbstractComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.logger = props.logger || new Logger();
        this.api: ApiInterface = props.api || new MockApi();
    }

    translate(namespace: string, key: string, args: ?[] = null, fallback: ?string): string {
        return new Translation(namespace, key, args, fallback).toString();
    }

    svgSprite(id: string, className: string = "") {
        return (
            <SvgSprite id={id} className={className} />
        )
    }

}
```

I also added some other things to show you more reason for a intermediate Component class.

So, all of this works! But flow complains about missing return types and so on, thats good with me, for that purpose i want to use flow! The problem i cant solve is the inheritance itself... But for me it does make a lot of sense.

Comment: umm is there any solid reason to use inheritance? React team [strongly discourage it](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance).

Comment: The Callout > ErrorMessage inheritance not but i would like to keep the AbstractComponent. Why? One simple example:

I wrote a translation utility to output translation strings, inside a react component it works like

{new Translation(namespace, id, args, fallback).toString()}

In order to use this i need to import the Translation class, so every compnent ends up with:
import Translation from "../Translation";

So i decided it would be useful to have a translate method inside of every react component i code, so i can simply write:

this.translate(args...)

Comment: So you tell me: Adopt your code because the react team thinks inheritance is not cool enough, they dont need it, i dont have to need it, know what? Facebook sucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to deal with inheritance (which I don't have an issue with, I just feel like you will probably run into issues later), you can do [something like the following](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0AbFAZxrgBkIBzZpKOAbwF9yrb6AWQhoA1gEEwwLr1IATJPyJx+dOABUoKAHY1qMYBG1dScFUZowoAVwzQAFNpQgkNMOiQAuOJajBtzAA0cKJIAJ7evv5BcChQzDTeAPxRAQDaALrBmCiUlABG6KLJqcwAlN4AbhDAcgDcpnAwEADKVtH2FT7tAQ2y-jDsOWhIcJLAAJLag1DDozx8FvAtlcwtYH6DcAC8cJ07AHxwADxywJVwAPQHfNRq4vm+6DAAwriQ2kjTxwAKOGCJGTBNooQbJHg7ODaax5I5IAAeg20cnoyGeADo3uAjF8YL9-jRgTBQUgjpxGmYUFJvOMpjM5o0KXBKCw2FBvDAwmAkBBMIxWexyGYzGgljY7FB7BsIACyiZhQqfNZuZLpbKGorhTAABbAGjolmsdiQtX6w1suAAH0tUKQAHd+UbJWUNZqmrr9VTpLtTeivVabZ8HcIxONOq6zLIFVYdHoSY5nK53CNIj0YqEIt0-AFgnEEiU05lIdC8tlcgUigXs+VU9X5W6iDBrFBjEGNFpdPpDNoEy43B5ghnc-FCXAcnlCmIyujmm1q+GmVHhTRVutNkh7LVa9FgqoaAA5RPbgKQgBEp7l5LdcEbzeM9iZ1+OKzWG2AW1q204tW4KjuB8TL890PFxf2uR9hTKRdSFkPcNFceAESRFExkeGMMCxD5cWOTgfFwLwsx3WIR2PZg4G4MlGiIZF2H2K9hVFXR4Fwmh8OHBJyMhHU9XRU1H1vFs9ggsxTnOG5rwVThuP1GNO3jYSJPwJw+2TJB8ECBTr3wDN1M0t00lYlx2JoLI9M1AADAASThDKQX9xwrMQ4D7GgUDYOA7XfbU4BlAwjFyOBrLzGhuHMsy4DKXgn0uM5KnEyCFUaXhuCAA):

```
class AbstractComponent<Props: {}, State: ?{} = null> extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    api: ApiInterface

    logger: typeof Logger

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.logger = props.logger || new Logger();
        this.api = props.api || new MockApi();
    }

    translate(namespace: string, key: string, args: ?string[] = null, fallback: ?string): string {
        return new Translation(namespace, key, args, fallback).toString();
    }

    svgSprite(id: string, className: string = "") {
        return (
            <SvgSprite id={id} className={className} />
        )
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
class Test extends AbstractComponent<{ some: string, args: string }> {
  render() {
    const { some, args } = this.props
     return (
        <div>
            {this.translate(
                'namespace',
                'key',
                [some, args],
                `${some} fallback message with optional ${args}`
            )}
        </div>
    )    
  }
}
```

Now, I will say that to some extent I understand where Facebook is coming from. Your component in this case is really already an abstract construct. And if you want this to be more flexible (let's say you have a stateless component that could benefit from having a `logger` and a `translate` function), you could do [one of two things](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecYCeYScAwhOBAHZJUwAqRJAvnAGZQVwDkUqG3AFCC0AGxQBnCXAAyEAObykUXM2FjJ0gLIQ0AawCCYYKuEATJBr5wNUuPSgoqE8TGDVcguDeoSYUAFcMaAAKKhQQJAkwdCQALjg-KGAqeWw9JAIEpJS0uBQoeQkEgH4c1IBtAF1sNhRRUQAjdD1S8vkASgSANwhgMwBuL3wIAGV-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-b9f13QD4NA20-DbA0cEvEioASGBLIkcNcMucMQrgAAfeLDSQd1XkectL3IsKIqi7tw3IhKkurXRDGMDK2IYtsws9WVhlYtj2O8WzeSmW1vDQXx4DwCyrJs2hsGajlWBucLgEi6KJGENj+2dfAmAgNg9NkjkrlWngRTFUzuB1JaWtGyL-OWXsEmnBq5uIBabEs6zbLJNbuA2xMqG2kort62yQn28NDqQY7DWNURLw6OqaSAA):

This is the defined type and translate function I'm using in both:

```
type CommonProps = {
  logger?: Logger,
  api?: ApiInterface,
  translate?: (namespace: string, key: string, args: ?string[], fallback: ?string) => string
}

// This should look familiar
function translate(namespace: string, key: string, args: ?string[] = null, fallback: ?string): string {
    return new Translation(namespace, key, args, fallback).toString();
}
```

#### Higher order component

```
function addCommonStuff({ logger = new Logger(), api = new MockApi(), translate = translate }: CommonProps) {
  return <Props: {}>(
    WrappedComponent: ComponentType<Props>
  ): ComponentType<
    $Diff<Props, $NonMaybeType<CommonProps>>
  > => (props: Props) => <WrappedComponent {...props} logger={logger} api={api} translate={translate} />
}
```

And used like:

```
class Test extends React.Component<{}> {}

const TestWithCommons = addCommonStuff({})(Test)

;<TestWithCommons />
```

#### Reusable component with a render prop

```
class Common extends React.Component<CommonProps & { render?: Function, children?: Function }, $NonMaybeType<CommonProps>> {
  state = {
    logger: this.props.logger || new Logger(),
    api: this.props.api || new MockApi(),
    translate: translate
  }

  render() {
    const { children, render } = this.props

    return typeof render === 'function' ? render(this.state) : (
      typeof children === 'function' ? children(this.state) : null
    )
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
class TestCommon extends React.Component<{}> {
   render() {
     return <Common>
       {({ logger, api, translate }) => translate('namespace',
        'key',
        null,
        `Fallback message`
      )}
    </Common>
   }
}
```

As an aside to this discussion, you don't need to write `defaultProps` as a getter for your callout. `static defaultProps = {}` should be enough. It shouldn't take passed in props into account or anything. If it does, you're better off using `state`

Comment: I already rolled everything back to a less complex approach because i dont want to implement some "bad practice". But thanks four your explanations, i am going to accept this answer because it actually answers the question.